# Returning cloud Firebase data from multiple promises at the same time

Tags: javascript, promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am still working on a better understanding of promises. I started with some samples from Doug Stevenson's YouTube videos on promises and then modified it to use my collections. This code most closely resembles the sample using areas and cities.

Here's the code:

```js
exports.getMatchesNew = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log("In On Call", data);
  return db.collection('matches').get()
  .then(areaSnapshot => {
      const promises = [];
      areaSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        var area = doc.data();
        // console.log("Area  is ", area.mentees);
        // console.log("area ID is ", area.id);

        // Loop through each mentee for a mentor
        for (const city in area.mentees)
        {
          // console.log("City is ", area.mentees[city]);

          // User Information for current mentee
          const p = db.collection('users').doc(area.mentees[city]).get();

          //User Information for current mentor
          const p2 = db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).get();
          //console.log("Doc ",p);
          // would like to combine this together, which will end up on one row
          // mentor name, mentee name
          promises.push(p, p2);
        }
      })
      
      return Promise.all(promises);
      //response.send(data);
  })
  .then(citySnapshots => {
    const results = [];
    citySnapshots.forEach(citySnap => {
      const data = citySnap.data();
      // this log entry is occuring once for each p and p2 from above.
      // I tried an array reference like citySnap[0] for mentee info and citySnap[1] for mentor info, this did not work.
      console.log("cSnap is: ", data);
      results.push(data);

    })
    return Promise.all(results);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle the error
    console.log(error);
    //response.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

The output is that I get the mentee first name and last name, then I get the output for the mentor first name and last name (on a separate row).

In the Firestore, each doc in the matches collection is simply the mentor's id and an array of mentee IDs. All user info is stored in a 'users' collection. 
So, I'm trying to loop through each matches doc, and produce one row of data for each mentor/mentee combination.

I still need to add some handling when p and/or p2 are not available.

My original intention for 'p' and 'p2' was to:

1. return first name and last name for p, rename them menteeFirstName and menteeLastName
2. return first name and last name for p2, rename them mentorFirstname and mentorLastName
3. combine this info and return an array of mentorFirstName, mentorLastName, menteeFirstName, menteeLastName.

However, I went down a rabbit hole with that. I decided to pare it back to working code, and post this.

So, can I combine the data from 'p' and 'p2'? Or am I doing this the wrong way?

I come from a relational db background, so the Firestore collections/documents concept with async calls is a new concept for me that I am becoming more familiar with (but not enough, yet).

I have tried to understand the various examples out there, but I think my unfamiliarity with promises is a major hurdle right now. 
I have tried both Roamer, and Steven Sark's suggestions.
Roamer's suggestion does not error out, but I believe it is dropping promises.

```js
exports.getMatchesNew = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return db.collection('matches').get()
  .then(areaSnapshot => {
      const promises = [];
      areaSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          var area = doc.data();
          for (let city in area.mentees) {
              const p = db.collection('users').doc(area.mentees[city]).get();
              const p2 = db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).get();
              promises.push(
                  Promise.all([p, p2]) // aggregate p and p2
                  .then(([mentee, mentor]) => {
                    var mentorInfo = mentor.data();
                    var menteeInfo = mentee.data();

                      console.log("Mentor: ", mentorInfo.lastName);
                      console.log("mentee: ", menteeInfo.lastName);
                      // return a plain object with all the required data for this iteration's doc
                      return {
                          // 'area': area, // for good measure
                          // 'city': city, // for good measure
                          'mentee': menteeInfo, // ???
                          'mentor': mentorInfo // ???
                      };
                  })
              );
          }
      })
      return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      //response.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

I see the data in the logs, but there are no records returned (or I am referencing them incorrectly in the .vue page

```
<template slot="mentorLastName" slot-scope="row">
          {{row.item.mentor.lastName}}
        </template>
        <template slot="menteelastName" slot-scope="row">
          {{row.item.mentee.lastName}}
        </template>
```

This works in other instances where the results contain these same objects.

Steven Sark's code also runs, based on the log files, with no errors. The difference is that the vue page never returns (always showing as 'thinking'). In the past, this meant there was an error in the cloud function. There is no error in the cloud function logs, and the data is NOT showing in the console function logs (whereas it is in the Roamer version). So I cannot prove that is working.

```js
exports.getMatchesNew = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log("In On Call", data);
  return db.collection('matches').get()
  .then(areaSnapshot => {
      const promises = [];
      areaSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        var area = doc.data();
        // console.log("Area  is ", area.mentees);
        // console.log("area ID is ", area.id);

        // Loop through each mentee for a mentor
        for (const city in area.mentees)
        {
          // console.log("City is ", area.mentees[city]);

          // User Information for current mentee
          const p = db.collection('users').doc(area.mentees[city]).get();

          //User Information for current mentor
          const p2 = db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).get();
          //console.log("Doc ",p);
          // would like to combine this together, which will end up on one row
          // mentor name, mentee name
          promises.push(p, p2);
        }
      })

      return Promise.all(promises);
      //response.send(data);
  })
  .then(citySnapshots => {

    let mentee = citySnapshots[0];
    let mentor = citySnapshots[1];
    console.log("Mentor: ", mentor.lastName);
    return {
      mentee,
      mentor
    };

  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle the error
    console.log(error);
    //response.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

I look at both of these modified examples, and feel like I'm understanding it, and then I smack myself when I don't get the results. I feel like both of these are dropping promises based on the log entries, but I don't understand how. It looks to me like these are chained or connected. That none are by themselves.

Comment: `Promise.all` expects an array or Promises, not data.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: This is something I am still trying to wrap my head around. I thought that .get() is a promise, and I'm pushing these to the promise.all. Maybe I am not understanding your comment Steven. Are you saying that I'm passing data and I shouldn't be?

Comment: @MikeRees, what makes the values/objects delivered by the promises into rows? Could you write some simple code with hard-coded data that successfully delivers rows to your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final working code. Thanks  to @Roamer-1888 and "@Steven Stark"

The final code is a bit is a cross between both of their offered solutions. Much appreciated help.

I am a little more comfortable with promises as a result. Hopefully I get to work with them a bit more to get more comfortable, and improve my chances of retaining it.

```js
exports.getMatchesNew = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return db.collection('matches').get()
  .then(areaSnapshot => {
      const promises = [];
      areaSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          var area = doc.data();
          for (let city in area.mentees) {
              const p = db.collection('users').doc(area.mentees[city]).get();
              const p2 = db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).get();
              if ( typeof p !== 'undefined' && p && typeof p2 !== 'undefined' && p2)
              {
                promises.push(
                    Promise.all([p, p2]) // aggregate p and p2
                );
              }
          }
      })
      return Promise.all(promises);
  })
    .then(citySnapshots => {
    const results = [];
    citySnapshots.forEach(citySnap => {
      var mentor = citySnap[1].data();
      var mentee = citySnap[0].data();
      
      if ( typeof mentee !== 'undefined' && mentee && typeof mentor !== 'undefined' && mentor)
      {
        var matchInfo = {
          mentor: {},
          mentee: {}
        }
        matchInfo.mentor = mentor;
        matchInfo.mentee = mentee;

        results.push(matchInfo);
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("Error missing mentor or mentee record, Need to research: ");
      }
    })
    return Promise.all(results);
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      //response.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

Comment: The second `.then()` appears to do nothing asynchronous. If so then its `return Promise.all(results);` can be simplified to `return results;`. I still prefer my inner `.then()` for performing the required synchronous transform of the data. I'm sure it's just a question of some simple debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Moved to an answer because it's too large for a comment:

I've never come across any examples that use `Promise.all` in that way ( using an array of data ), but maybe that's an example from an earlier Promise library like `Bliebird`, which is not applicable anymore.

here's a quick example for you:

```
Promis.all([ Promise.resolve('one'), Promise.reject(new Error('example failure') ])
.then( ( values ) => {
  //values[0] = data from promise 1; 'one'
  //values[1] = data from promise 2
})
.catch( ( error ) => {
  // note that an error from any promise provided will resolve this catch
})
```

EDIT:

As requested, here is your code modified to use Promise.all:

```
exports.getMatchesNew = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log("In On Call", data);
  return db.collection('matches').get()
  .then(areaSnapshot => {
      const promises = [];
      areaSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        var area = doc.data();
        // console.log("Area  is ", area.mentees);
        // console.log("area ID is ", area.id);

        // Loop through each mentee for a mentor
        for (const city in area.mentees)
        {
          // console.log("City is ", area.mentees[city]);

          // User Information for current mentee
          const p = db.collection('users').doc(area.mentees[city]).get();

          //User Information for current mentor
          const p2 = db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).get();
          //console.log("Doc ",p);
          // would like to combine this together, which will end up on one row
          // mentor name, mentee name
          promises.push(p, p2);
        }
      })

      return Promise.all(promises);
      //response.send(data);
  })
  .then(citySnapshots => {

    let mentee = citySnapshots[0];
    let mentor = citySnapshots[1];
    return {
      mentee,
      mentor
    };

  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle the error
    console.log(error);
    //response.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

another example without your db logic that I'm not quite following:

```
var response1 = { "foo": "bar" }
var response2 = { "biz": "baz" }


  return Promise.resolve( [ response1, response2 ] )
  .then(areaSnapshot => {
      const promises = [];
      areaSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          promises.push(Promise.resolve( doc ));
      })

      return Promise.all(promises);
      //response.send(data);
  })
  .then(citySnapshots => {

    let mentee = citySnapshots[0];
    let mentor = citySnapshots[1];
    return {
      mentee,
      mentor
    };

  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle the error
    console.log(error);
    //response.status(500).send(error);
  });
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get over the fact that I cannot press ENTER inside of this comment box. I will try your suggestion Steven. Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand how to implement this suggestion. I am assuming value[0] would be my 'p' and value[1] would be my 'p2'. This is assuming that all mentees have information and all mentors have information, such that each array would have the same elements. I cannot make that assumption. I'm trying to explicitly retrieve the connected information once. It doesn't make sense to me to retrieve all mentee info, then retrieve all mentor info, and then try to connect these. Maybe I'm just thinking about this the wrong way. Can you please offer some advice on implementing this suggestion?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include your code, modified.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I cannot tell if this runs correctly or not. I place a console.log entry in the .then which you added, and I am not seeing any console log entries as a result. It is not erroring out. The log has the two typical function execution sets (start/finished 204/200. I'm referring to the two objects in <template slot="mentorLastName" slot-scope="row">
          {{row.item.mentor.lastName}}
        </template>
        <template slot="menteelastName" slot-scope="row">
          {{row.item.mentee.lastName}}
        </template> and getting nothing displayed.

Comment: @Mike Reese sorry but I can't quite follow your db logic, so I edited my response with another example. 

I think you have issues with your loops. Connect to a debugger and step through the code, comparing to the simplified edit I just made, to find where the error is

Answer (score 0):

Your approach could be made to work but is rather messy due to the formation of one `promises` array containing both `p`s and `p2`s.

As far as I can tell, you want to bundle the required data for each doc into an object.

There's a number of ways in which this could be done. Here's one using an inner `Promise.all()` to aggregate each `[p,p2]` pair of promises, then form the required object.

```
exports.getMatchesNew = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return db.collection('matches').get()
    .then(areaSnapshot => {
        const promises = [];
        areaSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            var area = doc.data();
            for (let city in area.mentees) {
                const p = db.collection('users').doc(area.mentees[city]).get();
                const p2 = db.collection('users').doc(doc.id).get();
                promises.push(
                    Promise.all([p, p2]) // aggregate p and p2
                    .then(([mentee, mentor]) => {
                        // return a plain object with all the required data for this iteration's doc
                        return {
                            'area': area, // for good measure
                            'city': city, // for good measure
                            'mentee': mentee.data(), // ???
                            'mentor': mentor.data() // ???
                        };
                    });
                );
            }
        })
        return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        //response.status(500).send(error);
    });
});
```

*All on the assumption that `.get()` is asynchronous and `.data()` is synchronous*

The returned promise's success path will deliver an array of `{area,mentee,mentor}` objects.

May not be 100% correct because I don't fully understand the data. Shouldn't be too hard to adapt.

Comment: This suggestion looks like it will work. However, there is some syntax error that I haven't solved yet. It looks like all the parens and squigglies match up, but clearly I'm missing something. The error is : "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" Any idea?

Comment: Can't spot it. Try commenting out lines (intelligently) until the syntax error disappears.

Comment: Solved the syntax error, and getting a slightly different result than Steven's suggested code changes. With Steven's nothing is ever returned (the page just keeps spinning. With yours, the page comes back with no rows. Maybe I'm not referencing it properly in the .vue code. I'm referencing it like other examples on this site that reference objects in the results: <template slot="mentorLastName" slot-scope="row">
          {{row.item.mentor.lastName}}
        </template>
        <template slot="menteelastName" slot-scope="row">
          {{row.item.mentee.lastName}}
        </template>

Comment: You will undoubtedly need to do something with the array of objects delivered by the promise returned by `onCall(data, context)`. I don't know enough about your code or vue to advise. It could be something within the function, or maybe in its caller.